# Numpy Vector (N,1) dimension -> (N,) dimension conversion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a question regarding the conversion between (N,) dimension arrays and (N,1) dimension arrays. For example, y is (2,) dimension.

```
A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

x=np.array([1,2])

y=np.dot(A,x)

y.shape
Out[6]: (2,)
```

But the following will show y2 to be (2,1) dimension.

```
x2=x[:,np.newaxis]

y2=np.dot(A,x2)

y2.shape
Out[14]: (2, 1)
```

What would be the most efficient way of converting y2 back to y without copying?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) works for this

```
a  = np.arange(3)        # a.shape  = (3,)
b  = a.reshape((3,1))    # b.shape  = (3,1)
b2 = a.reshape((-1,1))   # b2.shape = (3,1)
c  = b.reshape((3,))     # c.shape  = (3,)
c2 = b.reshape((-1,))    # c2.shape = (3,)
```

note also that `reshape` doesn't copy the data unless it needs to for the new shape (which it doesn't need to do here):

```
a.__array_interface__['data']   # (22356720, False)
b.__array_interface__['data']   # (22356720, False)
c.__array_interface__['data']   # (22356720, False)
```

Answer (score 24):

Use [`numpy.squeeze`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([[[0], [1], [2]]])
>>> x.shape
(1, 3, 1)
>>> np.squeeze(x).shape
(3,)
>>> np.squeeze(x, axis=(2,)).shape
(1, 3)
```

Comment: This is more appropriate when the dimensions of the data is not known or there are too many troubles in getting appropriate dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

Slice along the dimension you want, as in the example below. To go in the reverse direction, you can use `None` as the slice for any dimension that should be treated as a singleton dimension, but which is needed to make shapes work.

```
In [786]: yy = np.asarray([[11],[7]])

In [787]: yy
Out[787]:
array([[11],
       [7]])

In [788]: yy.shape
Out[788]: (2, 1)

In [789]: yy[:,0]
Out[789]: array([11, 7])

In [790]: yy[:,0].shape
Out[790]: (2,)

In [791]: y1 = yy[:,0]

In [792]: y1.shape
Out[792]: (2,)

In [793]: y1[:,None]
Out[793]:
array([[11],
       [7]])

In [794]: y1[:,None].shape
Out[794]: (2, 1)
```

Alternatively, you can use `reshape`:

```
In [795]: yy.reshape((2,))
Out[795]: array([11,  7])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option in your toolbox could be [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```py
>>> y2.shape
(2, 1)
>>> y_ = y2.ravel()
>>> y_.shape
(2,)
```

Again, a copy is made *only* if needed, but this is not the case:

```py
>>> y2.__array_interface__["data"]
(2700295136768, False)
>>> y_.__array_interface__["data"]
(2700295136768, False)
```

For further details, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052011/14952856).

Answer (score 0):

the opposite translation can be made by:

```
np.atleast_2d(y).T
```