# Cannot reshape numpy array to vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn

I am trying to reshape an (N, 1) array `d` to an (N,) vector. According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871397/9270181) and my own experience with numpy, the following code should convert it to a vector:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import kneighbors_graph
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
X, labels = make_circles(n_samples=150, noise=0.1, factor=0.2)
A = kneighbors_graph(X, n_neighbors=5)
d = np.sum(A, axis=1)
d = d.reshape(-1)
```

However, `d.shape` gives `(1, 150)`

The same happens when I exactly replicate the code for the linked solution. Why is the numpy array not reshaping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the sklearn functions returned the nearest neighbor graph as a `sparse.csr.csr_matrix`. Applying `np.sum` returned a `numpy.matrix`, a data type that (in my opinion) should no longer exist. `numpy.matrix`s are incompatible with just about everything, and numpy operations on them return unexpected results.

The solution was casting the `numpy.csr.csr_matrix` to a `numpy.array`:

```
A = kneighbors_graph(X, n_neighbors=5)
A = A.toarray()
d = np.sum(A, axis=1)
d = d.reshape(-1)
```

Now we have `d.shape = (150,)`

Comment: `A.sum(axis=1).A1` is a shortcut